# Core dumped when using closedir if pathname is not printed after opendir

Tags: c

I have to code a ls like in C but I have some problems.
After opening a directory using opendir, if I'm not printing the pathname using printf or puts, I'll get a core dumped error when executing at closedir but if I do print the path, the code works fine.

```
const char * cwd=".";
DIR * dir=opendir(cwd);
//that print --> printf("%s",cwd);
if(dir==NULL){
    puts("ohlala");
}
char * filename;
struct dirent * truc;
struct stat * filestat=malloc(sizeof(struct stat *));
while((truc=readdir(dir))!=NULL){
    filename=truc->d_name;
    if(strcmp(filename,"..")!=0 && strcmp(filename,".")!=0){
        if(l==0){
            printf("%-s ",filename);
        }else if(l==1){
            if(stat(filename,filestat)!=0){
                printf("Erreur stat de %s\n",filename);
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("%ld %-s ",filestat->st_ino,filename);

        }
    }
}
//gdb is telling me the probleme is here
closedir(dir);
return 0;
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Something odd like that can be a tell of *undefined behaviour* somewhere.

Comment: Aside: what is the variable `l` (ell)? It is a very poor choice of name anyway, since if you have say `int hell = l;` you have to look carefully to see that is not a `1` (one).

Comment: Not that it should be a problem since you're looking at ".", but if `dir` is `NULL` you shouldn't just print something out - you should return from the function as well

Comment: @WeatherVane The l was to know if the option -l has been entered. (The program is to reproduce ls with some options). It's indeed something to avoid but since it's only for a short program and homework, I didn't really thought about it.

Comment: My point is proven in your comment where **l** (lower ell) and **I** (upper me) are indistinguishable. I suggest `int option_l;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allocating `filestat` correctly: this line

```
struct stat * filestat = malloc(sizeof(struct stat *))
```

should be

```
struct stat * filestat = malloc(sizeof(struct stat))
```

with no asterisk. Currently, the call to `stat` writes past the allocated memory block, causing undefined behavior.

Note that you don't need to allocate `filestat` dynamically: make it a local variable, and pass `&filestat` to `stat` call:

```
struct stat filestat;
...
if(stat(filename, &filestat) != 0) {
    ...
}
...
printf("%ld %-s ", filestat.st_ino, filename);
```

Comment: @DanKorn Yes, I was in the process of editing to make this suggestion. Thanks!